ffmpeg MP4 recording segmented and fragmented
I have the following command to record mp4 files from the webcam:
ffmpeg  -f video4linux2 -vcodec mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:2  -g 64 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -vcodec libx264 -crf 35 out.mp4

The MP4 file is fragmented because I need to take picture while the recording is running. That's way I can take the last frame from the video currently being recorded using the following command:
ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i out.mp4 -update 1 -q:v 1 out.jpeg

Everything is working good. But what I want now is instead of recording a single long video, I want to record in segment of 30 minutes, which can be done easily with the following command:
ffmpeg  -f video4linux2 -vcodec mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:2  -g 64 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -vcodec libx264 -crf 35 -segment_time 30:00 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 out_%d%m%y_%H%M%S.mp4

Now, when I run the command to take picture from the latest video, it does not work, throws the error:
moov atom not found

Is it possible to have the MP4 recording segmented as well as its keyframes fragmented so that I can take the last frame as picture?

Can you reproduce the issue using synthetic pattern? Example: ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=128x72:rate=1:duration=6000 -g 64 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -vcodec libx264 -crf 35 -segment_time 30:00 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 %04d.mp4 then ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i 0003.mp4 -update 1 -q:v 1 out.jpeg. Also, you may try using .mkv or .ts segment files instead of .mp4.
